# Playing a video in AR using Vuforia and Unity 5

Tags: unity, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am trying to play a video in augmented reality using Vuforia and Unity5. I followed a few videos but I am still not able to play it. Can anybody help? I get the "error texture icon" instead of the play icon.[image: The screen shot is attatched]

[image: screen shot of image target]